# Vagrant share - support for multiple sites in the same VM

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, hosts

I am running Vagrant 1.6.5 on my MacBook Pro and only use the [Laravel/Homestead box](https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead) along with the default homestead configs. I love the `vagrant share` feature however this apparently has no support for multiple sites in the same VM. I have researched a lot about this subject and have come up completely empty.

Right now, the supplied `vagrant share` just resolves to the default project site. I have no way to access other sites in my VM.

So, how can I use `vagrant share` with multiple sites? I really need to be able to access individual sites on the same VM externally.

I have tried to work with `xip.io` and map the site in my `Homestead.yaml` file [using this guide](http://christoph-rumpel.com/2014/10/access-laravel-homestead-projects-through-other-devices-in-three-little-steps/) but I was unable to get it working, and I'm not exactly sure *why*...somehow it screws up my homestead box and I have to `destroy` it and re `up` it.

If `vagrant share` isn't the solution for me, then what can you recommend?

Comment: i ran into the same issue... there's a solution that involves mapping ports and it's annoying. I found a hacky solution that works better for me. It seems that by default Vagrant Share will default to the first site listed in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/ folder. And those are always listed alphabetically.

So if you want to share a specific site.. just change add "aaa" or "123" to the url mapping. Or.. I suppose you could also simply rename the .conf file of the site you want and make sure it appears first and then reload nginx. Voila!

Comment: I figured this out a while back. I just map each site to a unique port (8001, 8002, etc). Then I modified the Homestead scripts on provision to assign each site the port in the nginx conf. Let's me Vagrant share like normal by specifying `--http 8001`.

Comment: doesn't that also require you to have to use those ports when accessing all your dev sites locally? I have over 30 sites on my dev.. having to not only assign 30 ports but then keep using those ports myself when accessing those sites on my dev just seems like extremely tedious...

Comment: It does, i have about 15 personally. Doesn't ever bother me. I keep a list handy if I need to look at it but otherwise the url's are saved in my browser so I generally don't need to remember anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can install a program called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which does a similar thing to `vagrant share` but works better with the multiple sites that Homestead uses. You will need to sign up for an account but basic usage is free.

Run: `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite your-local-site.app:80`

And it will be available globally on the url that ngrok gives you.

Answer (score 0):

If you `homestead edit` and add the following to the bottom of the file it'll probably help.

```
networks:
- type: public_network
  ip: "192.168.1.172"
  bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"
```

You can adjust the IP to be whatever you want. On a Mac, the "bridge" key works, but even then might be sketchy. If you launch the box and something is set up incorrectly, it'll give you an error like:

```
==> default: Available bridged network interfaces:
1) en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)
2) en1: Thunderbolt 1
3) en2: Thunderbolt 2
4) p2p0
5) awdl0
==> default: When choosing an interface, it is usually the one that is
==> default: being used to connect to the internet.
Vagrant is attempting to interface with the UI in a way that requires
a TTY. Most actions in Vagrant that require a TTY have configuration
switches to disable this requirement. Please do that or run Vagrant
with TTY.
```

Using this you can just copy and paste the correct interface into the `homestead.yaml` file and you should be on your way.

Don't forget to add your IP => hostname mapping in `/etc/hosts` or you'll have a bad time :)

Comment: This is now obsolete. Newer versions of homestead come with the ability to specify a port per site all pre-configured, although the docs don't mention it. If you dig into the scripts you'll see its there. This means you can just 'vagrant share --http 8020'